# Cannot Find Symbol Error while Javac compilation

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile the project that I obtained from https://github.com/Noahs-ARK/semafor-semantic-parser. I set up all the environment variables but for some reason I get a ton of errors about cannot find Symbol while Compilation. I am running on Windows 10.Can anyone take a look at it and please tell me what I am doing wrong? I would really appreciate it. Code runs on MacOS but not in Windows 10(using Cygwin) [image]

Code for Compilation File

```
source "$(dirname `readlink -f ${0}`)/config"
cd ${SEMAFOR_HOME}
pwd
classpath=".:./lib/semafor-deps.jar"

find edu \( -name "*.class" \) -exec rm '{}' \;
${JAVA_HOME_BIN}/javac -cp ${classpath}   edu/cmu/cs/lti/ark/fn/data/prep/CoNLLInputPreparation.java
${JAVA_HOME_BIN}/javac -cp ${classpath} edu/cmu/cs/lti/ark/fn/data/prep/AllAnnotationsMergingWithoutNE.java
${JAVA_HOME_BIN}/javac -cp ${classpath} edu/cmu/cs/lti/ark/fn/parsing/ParserDriver.java
${JAVA_HOME_BIN}/javac -cp ${classpath} edu/cmu/cs/lti/ark/fn/evaluation/PrepareFullAnnotationXML.java


cd ${MST_PARSER_HOME}
pwd
find mst \( -name "*.class" \) -exec rm '{}' \;
${JAVA_HOME_BIN}/javac -cp ".:./lib/trove.jar:./lib/mallet.jar:./lib/mallet-deps.jar" mst/DependencyEnglish2OProjParser.java
${JAVA_HOME_BIN}/javac -cp ".:./lib/trove.jar:./lib/mallet.jar:./lib/mallet-deps.jar" mst/DependencyParser.java
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provide your code.

Comment: Just added the code.